# React native with typescript passing useState as props

Tags: typescript, react-native, types

I have responsive.tsx file and I want to take an useState hook as props that contains orientation mode for app from app.tsx. I have an issue with types.

Argument of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props'. Property 'setOrientation' is missing in type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction>' but required in type 'Props

```
 //in responsive.tsx

type OrientationProp = {
    orientation:string
}
type Dispatcher<S> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>;
type Props = {
    setOrientation : Dispatcher<any>
}
const listenOrientationChange = ({ setOrientation  }:Props) => {
  Dimensions.addEventListener("change", (newDimensions) => {
    // Retrieve and save new dimensions
    screenWidth = newDimensions.window.width;
    screenHeight = newDimensions.window.height;

    // Trigger screen's rerender with a state update of the orientation variable
  });

  let orientation:OrientationProp = {
    orientation: screenWidth < screenHeight ? "portrait" : "landscape",
  };
  setOrientation(orientation);
};





//in app.tsx
    const [orientation,setOrientation] = useState(null);
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
    
        listenOrientationChange(setOrientation) // the error is here //Argument of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props'. Property 'setOrientation' is missing in type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' but required in type 'Props'
      },[])
```

Comment: Please, specify "an issue with types", but not in code comments. It would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `listenOrientationChange` to accept an object with a `setOrientation` property, but you are passing the `setOrientation` setter directly.

Either change the declaration of `listenOrientationChange` to be:

```
const listenOrientationChange = (setOrientation: Dispatcher<any>) => { ... }
```

or pass the `setOrientation` setter in an object:

```
useEffect(() => {
  listenOrientationChange({ setOrientation });
},[])
```

Edit: Here's how I would implement what you are trying to do:

```
// App.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

type Orientation = 'portrait' | 'landscape';

const useOrientation = (): Orientation => {
  const {width, height} = useWindowDimensions();
  return width < height ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
}

const App = () => {
  const orientation = useOrientation();
  return <Text>Orientation is {orientation}</Text>
};

export default App;
```

Snack here: https://snack.expo.io/IMFVdOlK7

Comment: How can I use with prop definitation. Like setOrientation:Props

Comment: Which code change did you go with from my answer, first or second? Once you reply I will update my answer.

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel I've edited my answer with my suggested solution to your overall goal of getting the orientation. react-native includes a `useWindowDimensions` hook that makes everything easier.

Comment: Yes I've thinked to use hook but I have theme file that contains fontsize etc and I am using like withWidthDp('5%') that come from responsive.tsx file . I update width and height according to orientation. So I can't figured out how I can use hook with theme .

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel if you provide a snack example I could help you better.

Comment: Are you available ?

Comment: Also. @CodeSikho  I am trying to implement hooks and I am worry because I've debug with console log. There was 7 re-rendering with 3 components when orientation changes and I can't imagine with 50,60 or 100 components . Is it oke ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's your code working: https://snack.expo.io/HFY1cQ!Ty

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I update the value in theme when oritentation changes ? Is it possible

Comment: I've found a solution. What do you think about that solution . Is it good ? You can find it in home.tsx file https://snack.expo.io/@ogulcankarayel/ex